# Framed minipage wrong size in PDF

Tags: boxes, minipage, lengths

I am trying to make a document containing a box with text that i want to appear a certain exact size when i print it. (Specifically I want to make a nametag that fits exactly inside a slot on my mailbox.) Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[c][3cm][c]{7.5cm}
    words
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that when i measure the lengths in the PDF (in Preview on macOS and printed on paper), the box is not 7.5 cm by 3 cm but rather (approximately) 7.9 cm by 3.2 cm. The paper size looks fine in Preview (approx. 21 cm  by 29.7 cm).

Is this an issue with the method I used to create the box, e.g. the `\fbox` doesn't fit exactly around the minipage? Or is it something else? Is there a better way to do this? I'm lost.

Comment: You have at least a space before and after your minipage; you should add `%` at the end of some lines. And note that `\fbox` adds `\fboxsep` space between the object and the frame.

Comment: to see why the spaces matter compare `\fbox{ x }` with `\fbox{x}`

Comment: A few `%`s and `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`did the trick. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides what others have already mentioned in the comments, here is a comparison with a `\rule{7.5cm}{3cm}` after subtracting `2*\fboxrule` width (2*0.4pt) to get the exact overall width of 7.5cm by 3cm.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}    
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr3cm-2\fboxrule][c]{\dimexpr7.5cm-2\fboxrule}
    words
\end{minipage}%
}

\rule{7.5cm}{3cm}    
\end{document}
```

[image]